# Keep asking for numbers and find the average when user enters -1

Tags: python, input, while-loop

```
number = 0
number_list = []

while number != -1:
  number = int(input('Enter a number'))
  number_list.append(number)
else:
  print(sum(number_list)/ len(number_list))
```

EDIT: Have found a simpler way to get the average of the list but if for example I enter '2' '3' '4' my program calculates the average to be 2 not 3. Unsure of where it's going wrong! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: `list` is a keyword.  Change it to something else.

Comment: Please show the actual traceback

Comment: `print(average)` doesn't actually call the `average` function.

Answer (score 1):

Trying out your code, I did a bit of simplification and also utilized an if statement to break out of the while loop in order to give a timely average.  Following is the snippet of code for your evaluation.

```
number_list = []

def average(mylist):
    return sum(mylist)/len(mylist)

while True:
  number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
  if number == -1:
      break
  number_list.append(number)
  
print(average(number_list));
```

Some points to note.

- Instead of associating the else statement with the while loop, I revised the while loop utilizing the Boolean constant "True" and then tested for the value of "-1" in order to break out of the loop.
- In the average function, I renamed the list variable to "mylist" so as to not confuse anyone who might analyze the code as list is a word that has significance in Python.
- Finally, the return of the average was added to the end of the function.  If a return statement is not included in a function, a value of "None" will be returned by a function, which is most likely why you received the error.

Following was a test run from the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Average$ python3 Average.py 
Enter a number: 10
Enter a number: 22
Enter a number: 40
Enter a number: -1
24.0
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

> converts the resulting list to Type: None

No, it doesn't. You get a ValueError with `int()` when it cannot parse what is passed.

You can try-except that. And you can just use `while True`.

Also, your average function doesn't output anything, but if it did, you need to call it with a parameter, not only print the function object...

ex.

```
from statistics import fmean

def average(data):
  return fmean(data)

number_list = []

while True:
  x = input('Enter a number')
  try:
    val = int(x)
    if val == -1:
      break
    number_list.append(val)
  except:
    break

print(average(number_list))
```

---

**edit**

> my program calculates the average to be 2 not 3

Your calculation includes the `-1` appended to the list , so you are running `8 / 4 == 2`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save all the `numbers` themselves, just save the `sum` and `count`.

You should check if the input is a `number` before trying to convert it to `int`

```
total_sum = 0
count = 0
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
    if number == '-1':
        break
    elif not number.isnumeric() and not (number[0] == "-" and number[1:].isnumeric()):
        print("Please enter numbers only")
        continue
    total_sum += int(number)
    count += 1

print(total_sum / count)
```